# Splitting c++ files between multiple product flavours

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-productflavors

My Android Studio module has two product flavours:

flavour1 uses NDK and incudes cpp files, whereas 
flavour2 doesn't use NDK and should not include cpp files.(The same issue happens when some `cpp` files are used only with `flavour1`, other `cpp` files are specific to `flavour2`).

I placed all cpp files in `flavour1/cpp` and expected it to do the job. However, what works for Java doesn't seem to work for `cpp`, as `cmake` always accepts files located in directory specified by `CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY`, i.e `main/cpp` and nothing else! Any other `cpp` files location produces error message:

`Failed to activate protocol version: "CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY" is set but incompatible with configured source directory value`.

The only work around, I can think of, is having different libraries for each product flavour. Is there a more natural approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can entirely disable `externalNativeBuild` based on the build flavor. What you could do is pass an argument to CMake based on the build flavor and just don't build any libraries in the flavor that you want to exclude the native libs from:

```
flavor1 {
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments "-DENABLE_NATIVE_LIBS=TRUE"
        }
    }
}

flavor2 {
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments "-DENABLE_NATIVE_LIBS=FALSE"
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION whatever you support)

if (NOT ENABLE_NATIVE_LIBS)
    return()
endif()

# Rest of your CMakeLists.txt here.
```

I haven't tested that, but it should work.